# Developing a servicestack API from a json structure

Tags: c#, servicestack

Api from a given json structure.
this is the first time i am working with a team and i am at the backend using c# while the other guy is frontend and is using json. so i have to develop an api based on the structure.

please any help will be appreciated.

below is a fragment of the json structure

```
    {  
   population:{  
      teachingstaff:222,
      nonteachingstaff:432,

   },
   staffs:[  
      {  
         name:"johnson",
         staffid:"dsf32",
         department:"HR department",
         phone:"233243242",
         email:"anth@ffs.com",
         type:"teaching",
         image:"../../../img/a2.jpg",

      },
      {  
         name:"jdohnson",
         staffid:"dsf32",
         department:"HR department",
         phone:"233243242",
         email:"anth@ffs.com",
         type:"non-teaching",
         image:"../../../img/a2.jpg",

      },
      {  
         name:"johernson",
         staffid:"dsf32",
         department:"HR department",
         phone:"233243242",
         email:"anth@ffs.com",
         type:"teaching",
         image:"../../../img/a2.jpg",

      },
      {  
         name:"johnccson",
         staffid:"dsf32",
         department:"HR department",
         phone:"233243242",
         email:"anth@ffs.com",
         type:"non-teaching",
         image:"../../../img/a2.jpg",

      },

   ],

}
```

Comment: What you are explaining is extremely vague. This JSON structure at this point is arbitrary in my mind. What does the API need to do? Is this JSON from a file on the server system? If it is coming from a remote endpoint, can't the frontend developer work with it like it is?

Comment: The API needs to translate the fields on d json structure to either string values or int values i think. And yes it is from a file on the server system and already the front end developer has developed a use interface.....what he wants is for me to translate it to c# service stack api inorder to store the values from the user interface to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is not an API but a way to deserialize the JSON structure into a .NET class instance. You can do this with a number of serializers. Last time I saw, servicestack provided its own, there is also the very popular JSON.NET library.

As a rule of thumb:

- a json object becomes a .NET class
- a value becomes a property
- a list becomes a .NET array or List.

To get you started, look at this:

```
class Whatevs {
  Population population { get; set; }
  List<Staff> staffs { get; set; }
}
```

You still need to fill in the blanks for the classes `Population` and `Staff`.